# Insert a "." in every break line of PDF

Tags: pdf

I am using coordinates and filters to select the information that I want to be selected from the PDF, the problem is that I need the blank spaces or line breaks to be placed in "." But the code fails to identify those line breaks. Any advice?

My code is:

```
import fitz
import re
import glob

# Coordenadas de selección
x1, y1 = 10,196
x2, y2 = 360,577

# Distancia máxima permitida entre líneas para que se consideren en la misma línea
distancia_linea = 10
# Distancia para imprimir un "."
distancia_punto = 47

...

# Recorrer cada archivo PDF
for archivo_pdf in archivos_pdf:
    # Abrir el archivo PDF
    documento = fitz.open(archivo_pdf)

    # Recorrer cada página del PDF
    for pagina_num in range(documento.page_count):
        # Obtener la página actual
        pagina = documento.load_page(pagina_num)

        # Obtener las palabras dentro de las coordenadas
        palabras = pagina.get_text_words()

        # Filtrar las palabras dentro de las coordenadas y que contengan solo letras mayúsculas, y sean permitidas
        palabras_seleccionadas = [palabra for palabra in palabras
                                  if x1 <= palabra[0] <= x2 and y1 <= palabra[1] <= y2
                                  and (re.match(r'^[A-Z]+$', palabra[4]) or palabra[4] in palabras_permitidas)
                                  and palabra[4] not in palabras_excluidas]

        # Ordenar las palabras según su posición vertical
        palabras_seleccionadas.sort(key=lambda palabra: palabra[1])

        # Agrupar las palabras seleccionadas por línea e imprimir un "." por cada espacio de al menos distancia_punto
        lineas = []
        linea_actual = []
        ultima_y = None
        ultima_palabra = None  # Inicializar ultima_palabra
        for palabra in palabras_seleccionadas:
            if not linea_actual:
                linea_actual.append(palabra)
                ultima_y = palabra[1]
            else:
                if abs(float(palabra[1]) - float(ultima_y)) >= distancia_punto:
                    lineas.append('.')
                    ultima_y = palabra[1]  # Actualizar ultima_y con el y de la nueva línea
                if ultima_palabra and abs(float(palabra[1]) - float(ultima_palabra[1])) <= distancia_linea:
                    linea_actual.append(palabra)
                else:
                    lineas.append(' '.join([palabra[4] for palabra in linea_actual]))
                    linea_actual = [palabra]
            ultima_palabra = palabra  # Actualizar ultima_palabra con la palabra actual
        if linea_actual:
            lineas.append(' '.join([palabra[4] for palabra in linea_actual]))

        # Imprimir las líneas seleccionadas
        for linea in lineas:
            print(linea)
```

I share with you an image of the PDF coordinates box, the red dots are where I need the "." and the highlighted in yellow is the selected information.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoFLc.jpg)

My output is:

```
AGUAYO AVILA R
M/S
ALCORTA SALA
.
M/S
AYALA PUENTE 
M/S
.
BLAS CASTIL
CABRERA GONZAL
```

The output i need is:

```
AGUAYO AVILA RAMIRO ALFREDO
M/S
ALCORTA SALAZAR ELIZABETH
M/S
AYALA PUENTE OSCAR ALEJANDRO
M/S
BLAS CASTILLO RODOLFO
.
CABRERA GONZALEZ VICTOR GERARDO
```